# Testing Python C libraries - get build path

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

When using setuptools/distutils to build C libraries in Python

```
$ python setup.py build
```

the `*.so/*.pyd` files are placed in `build/lib.win32-2.7` (or equivalent).

I'd like to test these files in my test suite, but I'd rather not hard code the `build/lib*` path. Does anyone know how to pull this path from distutils so I can `sys.path.append(build_path)` - or is there an even better way to get hold of these files? (without having installed them first)

Comment: I've wanted this on occasion too, but I've never been motivated enough to go looking for an answer ...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must get the platform that you are running on and the version of python you are running on and then assemble the name yourself. This is an internal detail of setuptools (based on the bundled version of distutils), and so is not guaranteed to be stable.

To get the current platform, use `sysconfig.get_platform()`.  To get the python version, use `sys.version_info` (specifically the first three elements of the returned tuple).  On my system (64-bit linux with python 2.7.2) I get:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> import sys
>>> sysconfig.get_platform()
linux-x86_64
>>> sys.version_info[:3]
(2, 7, 2)
```

##### Before setuptools 62.1

The format of the lib directory is "lib.platform-versionmajor.versionminor" (i.e. only 2.7, not 2.7.2).  You can construct this string using python's string formatting methods:

```
def distutils_dir_name(dname):
    """Returns the name of a distutils build directory"""
    f = "{dirname}.{platform}-{version[0]}.{version[1]}"
    return f.format(dirname=dname,
                    platform=sysconfig.get_platform(),
                    version=sys.version_info)
```

##### After setuptools 62.1

The directory above clashes with alternative python implementations like PyPy, so the internal build directory was made more specific using `sys.implementation.cache_tag`. The format of the lib directory is `"lib.<platform>-<cachetag>"`.  You can construct this string using python's string formatting methods:

```
def distutils_dir_name(dname):
    """Returns the name of a distutils build directory"""
    f = "{dirname}.{platform}-{cache_tag}"
    return f.format(dirname=dname,
                    platform=sysconfig.get_platform(),
                    cache_tag=sys.implementation.cache_tag)
```

You can use this to generate the name of any of distutils build directory:

```
>>> import os
# Before Setuptools 62.1
>>> os.path.join('build', distutils_dir_name('lib'))
build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
# After Setuptools 62.1
>>> os.path.join('build', distutils_dir_name('lib'))
build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython39
```

Note that Setuptools 62.1 is only available on Python 3.7+. Also, if you set `SETUPTOOLS_USE_DISTUTILS=stdlib` in your environment, then you will get the old behavior even in Setuptools 62.1.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping not to have to do - but thanks for the answer. Maybe one day I'll get round to writing that amazing python distribution package myself...

Comment: @danodonovan I was similarly disappointed when I wanted this information and found I had to write the above function.  It seems like something that should be easily accessible through distutils.  At least this way you can figure out the path programatically and don't have to hard-code it.

Comment: In shorter form:
python -c 'import sys,sysconfig; print("build/lib.{}-{}.{}".format(sysconfig.get_platform(), *sys.version_info[:2]))'

Comment: Note that on Python 3, Python modules go in just lib, so if your test scripts need access to that as well, you'll have to add this without the version info.

Comment: This is now invalid as of setuptools 62.1.0! Please do not use it. The build directory changed to fix clashes between PyPy and CPython (or any other alternative implementation). It now uses the build tag instead of `{platform}-{version[0]}.{version[1]}`.

Comment: @HenrySchreiner Please edit this answer to state this please.

Answer (score 6):

This is available as the `build_lib` member of the `build` command class, and it's relative to where `setup.py` would be. Getting at it when you're not actually running `setup` is rather nasty:

```
import distutils.dist
import distutils.command.build
b = distutils.command.build.build(distutils.dist.Distribution())
b.finalize_options()
print(b.build_lib)
```

Personally I'd go with SethMMorton's solution, since although it's potentially fragile if `distutils` changes the build directory location, I suspect playing these kinds of tricks is even more fragile if `distutils` structure changes.

Comment: A word of warning: `distutils.dist.Distribution()` won't be enough if, for instance, your `setup.py` builds a native extension. In that case, you might need to create a `Distribution` from your `setup.py`'s metadata dict.

Comment: You were correct, the build directory just changed in setuptools 62.1, fixing long standing bugs with PyPy + CPython, but invalidating the manual construction.

Answer (score 5):

I found that compiling the module in-place is best for testing purposes. To do so just use

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

This will compile all the auxiliary files in the temp directory as usual, but the final .so file will be put in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

@SethMMorton's approach is the way to go. It might be however safer (even if I don't know a platform for which his version doesn't work) to use `get_platform()` from `distutils.util` rather than from `sysconfig`.

This is how it is used in [distutils-library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Doc/includes/test.py#L190-L194):

```
import os
import sys
from distutils.util import get_platform
def get_distutils_lib_path():
    PLAT_SPEC = "%s-%d.%d" % (get_platform(), *sys.version_info[:2])
    return os.path.join("build", "lib.%s" % PLAT_SPEC)
```